# Pandas, cómo aplicar una función a cada fila

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

He creado un dataframe con `outers joins`  dandome la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar exceptuando `customer_id` las otras variables se repiten en bloque de tres. Esto lo fabrique así porque justo necesitaba crear nuevas columnas condicionadas para `acl` y `monto` de la siguiente forma:

```
merged_outer1['Delta_Monto'] = np.where((merged_outer1['monto_x']+merged_outer1['monto_y']+merged_outer1['monto'])>=1700, 1, 0)

merged_outer1['Delta_Acl'] = np.where((merged_outer1['acl_x']+merged_outer1['acl_y']+merged_outer1['acl'])>=9, 1, 0)
```

Dándome satisfactoriamente `Delta_Monto` y `Delta_Acl`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo lo que requiero para la columna `pendiente` es una condición distinta. Si en cualquier registro hay en alguna de las tres columnas `pendiente` un cambio de signo crear una columna llamada `Delta_Pendiente` con un `1` en caso contrario (es decir, si no hay cambio de signo) marcar con `0`. Alguien podría orientarme de como realizar esta condicional. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Este problema con `pandas`, es el de **aplicar una operación por vector a un dataframe basandonos en los valores de dicho vector**. Debido a que no es del todo sencillo, he definido un problema genérico que responde a tu pregunta, cualquier duda, por favor pregúntame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar el método de los DataFrames `.apply()` este método te **permite aplicar una operación por vector**, es decir por filas o por columnas y obtener un resultado combinandolo si lo combinamos con una función `lambda`.

**Para explicarlo con un problema reproducible**, voy a crearme un ejemplo de como sería con tus datos. Vamos a suponer que tenemos el siguiente problema:

> Tenemos un conjunto de 100 datos con las calificaciones de matemáticas, lengua, religión, historia, y gimnasia. Tenemos que crearnos una nueva columna en la que almacenemos los alumnos que han pasado de curso, para ello es necesario que su calificación en matemáticas, lengua e historia sea mayor o igual a 5

Perfecto, primero vamos a crear un `DataFrame` con datos aleatorios:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Definimos una matriz (100, 5) con 100 alumnos y las 5 asignaturas
calificaciones = (np.random.random((100, 5))*10).round(2)

df_alumnos = pd.DataFrame(calificaciones, columns=["matematicas", "lengua","religion", "historia", "gimnasia"])
```

Ahora tenemos un dataframe de este estilo, con 100 alumnos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## ¿Cómo usar apply()?

El método `apply()` necesita dos parámetros:

1. `func`: la función que queremos aplicar por vector, en este caso es un condicional, que marque si pasamos o no de curso y devuelva uno o cero.
2. `axis`: a que vectores queremos aplicarle dicha operación, en este caso, como queremos iterar por cada fila, será a los vectores fila, por lo que será `axis=1` (si ponemos 0, será por columna).

Lo único que tenemos que hacer es crear una función que nos devuelva uno o cero en base a si a aprobado las asignaturas correspondientes, por lo que me creo la función `pasa_de_curso()`:

```
def pasa_de_curso(matematicas, lengua, historia):
    return 1 if matematicas >= 5 and lengua >=5 and historia >=5 else 0
```

Ya tenemos todo lo necesario para utilizar `.apply()` por lo que nos creamos una nueva columna de ceros y unos basada en nuestra función:

```
df_alumnos["pasan_curso"] = df_alumnos.apply(lambda x: pasa_de_curso(x[0], x[1], x[3]), axis=1)
```

### ¿Por qué usamos lambda?

Como hemos dicho previamente, `apply()` coge todo un vector (una fila en nuestro caso) para aplicarle una operación, pero nosotros no queremos aplicarle una operación a esa fila por completo, queremos escoger ciertos elementos de la fila. Por que nuestra función `pasa_de_curso()` se vera **envuelta** en otra función (`lambda`).

Lo que está sucediendo es lo siguiente:

1. `apply()` le entrega la primera fila a la función `lambda`.
2. La función `lambda` contiene una función llamada `pasa_de_curso()` a la que `lambda` le entrega la fila, nosotros mediante los índices, seleccionamos aquellos valores de la fila que queremos y se le pasarán a `pasa_de_curso()`
3. Se realiza la operación `pasa_de_curso()` y nos devuelve el resultado, que finalmente será almacenado en nuestra nueva variable.

Por último, puedes ver todo esto en la [documentación oficial de Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)